# Bash tab-completion not working

Tags: bash-completion

I am trying to troubleshoot why the bash tab-completion isn't working on my fedora 19 desktop.
I am afraid I just know what else to add to this that might be relevant.

Comment: Do you have this in your .bashrc ? 

bind '"\t":menu-complete'

Comment: I don't. But your answer made me think of /etc/bashrc that I source. It seems commenting that resolves this.

Comment: @Nishant isn't readline already setup? I don't have this set but completion works

Comment: @MiserableVariable You are right. One should check  /etc/bash_completion entry

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause is lines like..:

```
set disable-completion on
```

.. in `~/.inputrc`. I don't know what puts that there, but if I deleted it then I found it was recreated every time I started a shell via firejail. However, if I edited it to `off` instead of `on` tab completion worked as usual.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on Debian 12 was installing the `bash-completion` package:

```bash
sudo apt-get install bash-completion
```

Then I restarted the shell, and the completions were working.